# Need vbscript to find out redirected page's URL for an input URL

Tags: url, redirect, vbscript

I have `http:\\URL_MAIN` url as input. This, when opened in web browser, immediately opens a popup screen with two possibilities- 
a. Either pop up screen will show a web page with `http:\\URL_SUCCESS` url OR
b. pop up screen will show a web page with `http:\\URL_FAILURE`

I need a vbscript where I can input my `http:\\URL_MAIN`, and in return, it should tell me which URL its redirecting to in the popup screen. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [url checker VBA, when redirected, show redirected url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982860/url-checker-vba-when-redirected-show-redirected-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This vbscript can did the trick :

```
Option Explicit
Dim strUrl,Title
Title = "Get Header Location"
Do  
    strUrl = InputBox("Copy and paste your link here to get the response header",_
    Title,"http://www.vbfrance.com/")
    If Len(strUrl) = 0 Then 
        Exit Do
    Else 
        MsgBox GetHeaderLocation(strUrl),vbExclamation,Title
    End if
Loop Until IsEmpty(strUrl)  
wscript.Quit()
'**************************************************************
Function GetHeaderLocation(strUrl)
    On Error Resume Next
    Const WHR_EnableRedirects = 6
    Dim oHttp,Target
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oHttp.Option(WHR_EnableRedirects) = False
    oHttp.Open "HEAD", strUrl, False
    oHttp.send
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If oHttp.Status = 200 Then
            Target = "There is no redirection " &_
            oHttp.Status & " " & oHttp.statusText & vbcrlf &_
            "for this URL : " & chr(34) & strUrl & chr(34)
        ElseIf oHttp.Status = 301 Or oHttp.Status = 302 Then
            Target = "This URL is redirected to : " & vbCrlf &_
            chr(34) & oHttp.getResponseHeader("Location") & chr(34)
        End If
    Else
        GetHeaderLocation = "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrlf &_
        Err.Source & " " & Err.Description
    End If
    GetHeaderLocation = Target
End Function
'**************************************************************
```